# Kubernetes is sending request to internal ip to check logs

Tags: kubernetes

i have 2 servers.

1. master on AWS
2. dedicated server worker node on local hosting

first when i was running `sudo kubeadm init` command on my master server i wasn't able to join worker node then i realize that it's running API server on private IP of AWS so then i added `--control-plane-endpoint=PUBLIC_IP_OF_AWS_SERVER`

then i was able to join worker node.

but when worker node is ready then i run `kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/pods/commands.yaml` on master server and trying to get pods i can see the pod is created but when i check logs of that pod with this command `kubectl logs -f command-demo`

i get this issue

`Error from server: Get "https://192.168.1.109:10250/containerLogs/default/command-demo/command-demo-container?follow=true": dial tcp 192.168.1.109:10250: i/o timeout`

as you can see master node is sending request to worker node private/internal ip so i think because of that request it get's timeout how can i tell master to send request to my worker node public ip to get logs? or how can i fix this issue?

Comment: I think setting only `--control-plane-endpoint=PUBLIC_IP_OF_AWS_SERVER` in your `kubeadm init` won't be enough and you'll also need to set `--apiserver-advertise-address`.

Comment: @mario what should i set `apiserver-advertise-address` equal to?

Comment: same `PUBLIC_IP_OF_AWS_SERVER` that you've already set for `--control-plane-endpoint`